# defaultValue vs placeholder for input fields

Tags: javascript, admin-on-rest

Is there a way to use a placeholder for aor input fields?

The key difference between the two is that a placeholder won't show up as value when submitted, while a defaultValue will.

Is there a notion of placeholder in aoe inputs? If not, why?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use a placeholder for aor input fields?

Yes there is! example:

```
<ImageInput source="pictures" label="Related pictures" accept="image/*" placeholder={<p>Drop your file here</p>}>
    <ImageField source="src" title="title" />
</ImageInput>
```

or

```
<Field name="lat" component="input" type="number" placeholder="latitude" />
```

here's the reference: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/docs/Inputs.md - search for keyword `placeholder`

Comment: Thanks for the response, though there is no placeholder attributes for input fields.